# Chart.js adds unwanted padding on top and below chart with padding set to 0

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, chart.js

It's my first time using Chart.js, everything is working fine except for one thing.
For some reason the chart adds unwanted padding on top and below which makes it look squished. (look image below)
[canvas unwanted padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9oib.png)
I would like my canvas to be 180x180 with the chart being 180x180 aswell. How would I achieve this?

added chart code below:

```
let ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: this.strawpoll.answers.filter(data => data.amount > 0).map(data => data.name),
    datasets: [{
      data: this.strawpoll.answers.map(data => data.amount).filter(data => data > 0),
      backgroundColor: this.sliceColor,
      borderColor: this.borderColor,
      hoverBorderColor: this.borderColor,
      borderWidth: 4,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0
      }
    },
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you give the parent-div of your chart the wanted 180x180pixels, you can add to your options

```
chartArea: { width: '100%', height: '100%', top: 0}
```

grts Kevin